# Perform action after rewarded ad avoiding exploitation

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I want to implement a feature in my Android app that after a rewarded ad the user can perform an action (that is an HTTP request), is there any way to do that and also avoiding that someone could modify the app avoiding the ad but performing the action anyways?

I could do all of this with a server in the middle but I would like to avoid it